# track change in an array then submit the array to the same page

Tags: php, arrays, post, submit

I have the following php code (I omitted the irrelevant part of code):

```
<?php
echo "<form action=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF] method=\"POST\">"; 
echo "<table>"; 
for ($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i+=1) {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align=center>$variable1[$i]</td>";  
    echo "<td align=center>$variable2[$i]</td>";  
    echo "<td align=center><input type=\"text\" name=\"variable3[$i]\" value=\"$variable3[$i]\" /></td></tr>";  
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"variable1[$i]\" value=\"$variable1[$i]\">";  
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"variable2[$i]\" value=\"$variable1[$i]\">";  
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"variable3[$i]\" value=\"$variable1[$i]\">";  
}  
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><input name=\"action\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\"></td></tr>";  
echo "</table>";  
echo "</form>";  
?>
```

I want to pass the variables through POST method to the same page. The code retrieves data from the database and lists it in a table. However, I want to be able to manually modify variable3 and submit the array after I do this. The problem is that the array is submitted before I modify the variable3. How can I submit the array with the value of variable3 modified? How can I check if variable3 was modified and do the submitting afterwards? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what  you've tried already?

Comment: your input can't be modified if you keep your hidden input with the same name. variable3 is used two time, one for the user to change it and one time with the hidden value, so you won't receive the user input.

Comment: That is exactly my question. What do I have to do to receive the user input on variable3? I want the user to be able to modify variable3 and then submit the array, through Update button to the same page. Is it possible?

Comment: Then delete your 
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"variable3[$i]\" value=\"$variable1[$i]\">";
and it's done

Comment: Thanks @DDA. That did the trick. One more question though. How do I determine which values where modified by the user and update the mysql database accordingly?

Comment: Usually, we update without checking if info has changed. But if you want just write someting like 
if(isset($_POST['variable3']) && $_POST['variable3']!=$variable3){ //update; }

Comment: ... but don't forget to bind and secure your $_POST values with pdo or sqli and their prepare statment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete line 11 like this

```
<?php
echo "<form action=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF] method=\"POST\">"; 
echo "<table>"; 
for ($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i+=1) {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align=center>$variable1[$i]</td>";  
    echo "<td align=center>$variable2[$i]</td>";  
    echo "<td align=center><input type=\"text\" name=\"variable3[$i]\" value=\"$variable3[$i]\" /></td></tr>";  
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"variable1[$i]\" value=\"$variable1[$i]\">";  
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"variable2[$i]\" value=\"$variable1[$i]\">";  
}  
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><input name=\"action\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\"></td></tr>";  
echo "</table>";  
echo "</form>";  
?>
```

Now you can see if it has been changed by cheking the value of $_POST['variable3'].